# clang can't detect initialisation and gives an error

Tags: c++

I tried compiling a simple program using clang but I got following error code:

kassa.cpp:7:13: error: expected ';' at end of declaration

```
    double mwst{0.8};
               ^
               ;
```

1 error generated.

I downloaded clang 3.8-36 on a debian based system using the command:

sudo apt-get install clang

For some reason it works with gcc or using assignments, but I want it to work normally with clang as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, and also please tell us how you build the source and what flags you provide to `clang++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using quite an old version of Clang, which uses the old C++98 standard by default.

You need to add the `-std=c++11` option to the compiler command line in order to support C++11 or `-std=c++14` for C++14. The type of initialization with braces that you are trying to use was introduced with C++11.

Your are advised to upgrade Clang to a more recent version, because that version is not going to support any more recent C++ standard versions such as the current C++17 and the upcoming C++20.

Since you installed it through `apt-get` this also suggests that you are using an old Linux distribution, which may be fine if it is still supported (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). If not, I would urge you to upgrade your whole system. But even if, you might want to consider upgrading to more easily use new software features.

Comment: I updated my system and now I am using a newer version of clang. Now it works. Thanks!